# Android WebView: intercept error 404 on one element (not entire page)

Tags: android, webview, error-handling, android-webview

I am trying to make WebView display remote image (with certain stylistic tweaks). This works perfectly by loading WebView with an HTML snippet that references that remote IMG amongst other things. But the only problem is that sometimes this remote image is not present which results in a broken image icon.

What I would like to do is to intercept the (un)availability of the remote image and recover by switching to another one. I've tried using `onReceivedError()` of `WebViewClient` but somehow it does not trigger even when the image is not available.

My current image loading logic is as follows:

```
String url = "...";     // remote image URL
String html = String.format("<style>img{display: inline;" +
                            "height: auto;max-width: 100%%;}</style>" +
                            "<img src=\"%s\"></img>", url);

wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, 
                                WebResourceError rerr) {
        Log.e("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code: " + errorCode);
    }
});

wv.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
```

I suspect `onReceivedError()` only triggers for page-level errors and I'm not sure how to make it trigger for element-level errors. Any help would be very appreciated.

PS. While typing this, I've just thought about handling it in JS - that is, load webview with a JS snippet that tries to load the remote image and in case of an error loads another one - all within the JavaScript realm. I'll try it and if it works will post it here as well.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the JavaScript solution works, although the question about intercepting in Android real still remains. Here's the JavaScript way:

```
    String url = "...";         // real image
    String backup_url = "...";  // backup image

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fullImageWebView);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // FIXME: put into assets as an HTML file
    String template = "" +
            "<style>\n" +
            " img {\n" +
            "     display: inline;\n" +
            "     height: auto;\n" +
            "     max-width: 100%%;\n" +
            " }\n" +
            "</style>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<img id='image'></img>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<script>\n" +
            " var second_attempt = false;\n" +
            " var img = document.getElementById('image');\n" +
            " img.src = '%s';\n" +
            "\n" +
            " window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {\n" +
            "     if (!second_attempt) {\n" +
            "         second_attempt = true;\n" +
            "         img.src = '%s';\n" +
            "     }\n" +
            " }, true);\n" +
            "</script>";


    String html = String.format(template, url, backup_url);
    wv.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
```